# Heroku - Time delayed function

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a function that checks every minute if it is 7:30am, and if it is time, it sends me a text message.

But since I upload to heroku and my time zone is different, I have to adjust the time ahead to look like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  let date = new Date();
  if(date.getHours() == 11 && date.getMinutes() == 30){
    sendDaily()
  }
}, 60000)
```

But when I upload to heroku, I get alerts on my phone at random times.  I have also tried using the `schedule` package that helps with this, but the same error occurs, the function does not run when supposed to.  I have also tried changing the timezone on heroku but it doesnt help because when I enter my city/location it still gives the same default time zone time.

Comment: maybe moment.js or dayjs helps 
https://momentjs.com/
https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is built on AWS and create containers on any center it deems fit. Which means your application can be running anywhere in the world as shown on this [AWS infrastructure map](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/). With that being said using `new Date` on a server will have a very different outcome based on which server it is created in, which you have no control over.

How do you solve this problem?

You need to decouple the dependency of `new Date` on the OS.

Options

1. You can use an API that returns a standard time of day which would create a single source of truth for all AWS containers no matter where they are. Here is an [Example](http://worldclockapi.com/) of this.
2. You can manually set the Time Zone assuming all the AWS OS clocks are in sync. You can do this with [moment](https://momentjs.com/) and [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)
3. Using a dedicated server that is not created randomly throughout the world. Like any tradeoffs, this creates its own issues if you are trying to scale but it is an option.